# Custom column extension for slick

Tags: scala, slick

SQL expression generated by `table.filter(_.id.inSetBind(someSet))` has restrictions for Oracle DB:

1. `someSet` must contains no more than 1000 elements (ORA-01795)
2. Oracle builds different excecution plans for queries with different size of someSet.

I want to create column extension, `inArrayBind[T](s: Traversable[T])`, that instead of creating query `select ... where x IN (...)`, first creates Oracle type `create or replace type MY_ARRAY IS varray(sizeOfSet) of type T` and then perfrorms `select ... where x in MY_ARRAY`

Is there way to achieved this with slick?